# UE4 Navmesh precision

Tags: path-finding, unreal-4, navmesh

I'm trying to make my very tiny man pathfind his way through a map of a school but the navmash won't recognize some of the hallways cause they are very narrow like this.[image]

So as you can see the man can fit but the navmesh says no so can anyone help and keep in mind that i am very new to unreal engine so please make your explanation easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

A Navmesh is generated according to so-called "Nav Agents".

These Nav Agents are located in your Project Settings under the "Navigation System" Settings. There you can create a new Agent or edit existing ones.

To make your Navmesh go through narrow corridors, you need to change the "Nav Agent Radius".
Keep in mind that if your Nav Agent Radius is smaller than your AI's Collision, the AI will probably get stuck!

[image]